# how to use if condition in linux

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
echo "Enter a grade"
read grade
if test $grade="A"
then
  basic=6000
elif test $grade="B"
then
  basic=5000
else
  basic=4000
fi
echo "Your basic is $basic"
```

When I execute this code in terminal with any grade it always returns "Your basic is 6000". what is the mistake in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a space around the =.

As it is now, you just give the test command one argument, which is $grade="A", since space separates arguments. If you put spaces around =, then test will have 3 arguments, i.e. (an expanded) $grade, = and "A".

Thus:

```
echo "Enter a grade"
read grade
if test $grade = "A"
then
  basic=6000
elif test $grade = "B"
then
  basic=5000
else
  basic=4000
fi
echo "Your basic is $basic"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a grade"
# Read single char
read -n 1 grade
echo $grade
if [ "$grade" == 'A' ]; then
    basic=6000
elif [ "$grade" == 'B' ]; then
    basic=5000
else
    basic=4000
fi
echo "Your basic is $basic"
```

Comment: Yes, that is closer to how I would write it myself. Perhaps also "read -p", i.e. `read -p "Enter a grade: "`.